# Why "resolve" method always calls the class constructor that is already registered in Unity?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, prism, ioc-container

I use **Unity** and **Prism** in my WPF application.
I have a class that is registered to the `Container` in the Bootstrapper in this way:

```
Container.RegisterType<MyClass>();
```

The class has a constructor has `ILoggerFacade` interface as a parameter:

```
private ILoggerFacade _logger;

    public MyClass(ILoggerFacade logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        //do some stuff
    }
```

When I try to resolve that class instance, I realized that class constructor is called while returning the instance. So, all stuff is done from scratch. I resolve the instance this way:

```
MyClass a = Container.Resolve<MyClass>();
```

What is the reason behind calling constructor each Resolve method I execute?

Comment: Looks like a problem with [lifetime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660872(v=pandp.20).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you doesn't want your component to be instancied at each resolve, you need to declare its lifetime as ContainerControlled :

`myContainer.RegisterType<MySingletonObject>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());`

see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx#sec34 but be careful of side effects, as your object will behave like a singleton

Answer (score 2):

Unity uses the transient lifetime manager by default (when you do not specify another lifetime manager). The transient lifetime manager will give you a NEW instance of the registered type each time you call resolve. There are other lifetime managers that can be specified during registration that will provide different behavior (singleton, etc.)